# DataSource is null - Deploy on OpenShift JBOSS AS 7

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss

I developing a project with hibernate and spring.
I use annotations for all.
I'm trying to deploy in OpenShift in JBOSS AS 7.
All time I get errors with the DataSource bean and I not know what I doing wrong.

In the log appear:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [clanwar/config/MainConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource clanwar.config.MainConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You can check the full stack trace here: http://clanwaropenshift-stel.rhcloud.com/

My DataSource bean:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    Driver driver = null;
    try {
        driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dataSource.setDriver(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty(JDBC_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty(JDBC_USER));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(JDBC_PASSWORD));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Also I try with `DriverManagerDataSource` and `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` but all time I get the same error.

Thanks in advance.

1 EDIT

When the app is deploying, the logger shows create two times the dataSource.
First show: 
env -> `StandardServletEnvironment {activeProfiles=[], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment,class path resource [application.properties]]}`
datasource -> `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@b8dec7`

But the second time shows:
env -> `null`
datasource -> `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1133cea`

Part of the log:

```
014/12/22 11:39:42,848 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Dec 22 11:39:42 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014/12/22 11:39:43,035 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Registering annotated classes: [class clanwar.config.MainConfig,class clanwar.config.MvcConfig,class clanwar.config.SecurityConfig]
2014/12/22 11:39:43,673 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Overriding bean definition for bean 'propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=mainConfig; factoryMethodName=propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class clanwar.config.MainConfig] with [Root bean: class [clanwar.config.MvcConfig]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class clanwar.config.MvcConfig]
2014/12/22 11:39:44,443 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2014/12/22 11:39:45,385 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:45,394 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:45,394 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:45,400 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) StandardServletEnvironment {activeProfiles=[], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment,class path resource [application.properties]]}
2014/12/22 11:39:45,401 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@b8dec7
2014/12/22 11:39:45,407 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:45,407 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:45,409 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:45,641 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
2014/12/22 11:39:45,648 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
2014/12/22 11:39:45,652 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2014/12/22 11:39:45,655 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2014/12/22 11:39:46,467 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): clanwar.model.ClanMember
2014/12/22 11:39:46,467 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): clanwar.model.ClanMember
2014/12/22 11:39:46,469 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): clanwar.model.WarPlayer
2014/12/22 11:39:46,469 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): clanwar.model.WarPlayer
2014/12/22 11:39:46,621 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"'.
2014/12/22 11:39:46,630 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2014/12/22 11:39:46,666 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2014/12/22 11:39:46,735 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2014/12/22 11:39:46,758 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014/12/22 11:39:46,950 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
2014/12/22 11:39:48,873 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-3) Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource@1828bd6] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2014/12/22 11:39:49,639 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-3) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Dec 22 11:39:42 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014/12/22 11:39:49,861 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/war/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.WarController.warHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,866 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/war/create],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.WarController.createWarHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,877 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/war/new],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.WarController.newWarHandler(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,878 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/war/search],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.WarController.searchWarHandler(int)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,879 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/war/saveplayer],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.WarController.savePlayerInWarHandler(clanwar.model.WarPlayer)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,888 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/createPinpinelas],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void clanwar.controller.HelperController.playerSaveHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,893 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/json/test],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public clanwar.model.WarPlayer clanwar.controller.HelperController.jsonTest()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,893 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/test],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.HelperController.mvcTest()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,901 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/login],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.LoginController.playerLoginHandler(java.lang.String)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,914 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/signup],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.LoginController.signUpViewHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,920 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/signup],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.LoginController.signUpHandler(clanwar.model.Player)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,922 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/clan/choose],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.ClanController.clanChooseHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,932 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/clan/new],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.ClanController.clanNewViewHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,933 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/clan/new],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.ClanController.clanNewHandler(clanwar.model.Clan,java.lang.String)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,933 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/clan/select],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.ClanController.clanSelectHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,934 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/clan/view],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.ClanController.clanViewHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,934 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/clan/join],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.ClanController.clanJoinHandler(clanwar.model.ClanMember)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,935 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/clan/leave],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.ClanController.clanLeaveHandler(clanwar.model.ClanMember)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,939 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.MainController.homeHandler(java.security.Principal)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,940 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/denied],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.MainController.deniedHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,941 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/json/war],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public clanwar.model.War clanwar.controller.JsonController.jsonWarHandler(int)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,941 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/json/wars],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<clanwar.model.War> clanwar.controller.JsonController.jsonWarsHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,943 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/player/update],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void clanwar.controller.PlayerController.playerUdapteHandler(clanwar.model.Player)
2014/12/22 11:39:49,950 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/player/profile],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.PlayerController.profileHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,950 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped "{[/player/password],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView clanwar.controller.PlayerController.passwordHandler()
2014/12/22 11:39:49,998 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-3) Mapped URL path [/web/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014/12/22 11:39:51,306 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-3) Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/web/**'], []
2014/12/22 11:39:51,447 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-3) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1c1d169, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@128953, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@10bcae, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5e8f18, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@c1924a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@ac9750, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@29470e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@baae53, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@37eaff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@19b7bc4, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@f6d8e6, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@137a0cf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@629d2e]
2014/12/22 11:39:51,573 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-3) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8731 ms
2014/12/22 11:39:51,636 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (MSC service thread 1-3) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring/spring-context'
2014/12/22 11:39:51,649 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-3) FrameworkServlet 'spring/spring-context': initialization started
2014/12/22 11:39:51,688 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring/spring-context-servlet': startup date [Mon Dec 22 11:39:51 EST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2014/12/22 11:39:51,742 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-3) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-context-servlet.xml]
2014/12/22 11:39:52,976 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Overriding bean definition for bean 'propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer': replacing [Root bean: class [clanwar.config.MvcConfig]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [clanwar/config/MvcConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=mainConfig; factoryMethodName=propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [clanwar/config/MainConfig.class]]
2014/12/22 11:39:53,116 WARN  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer] (MSC service thread 1-3) @Bean method MainConfig.propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details
2014/12/22 11:39:53,193 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2014/12/22 11:39:53,489 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:53,495 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:53,497 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:53,497 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) null
2014/12/22 11:39:53,497 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1133cea
2014/12/22 11:39:53,497 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:53,497 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
2014/12/22 11:39:53,498 INFO  [clanwar.config.MainConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) ___________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Unfortunately the actual root cause is swallowed. I'm sure openshift has some support for application logging, so log if either 'driver' or 'env' is null to at least be able to narrow down what exactly is null in your code.

Comment: @Gimby I editted my question.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not come to your mind when you realized that env is actually null to actually add the code that shows where env comes from.

Comment: @Gimby I solve the issue becouse I doing the config two times on deploy. Anyway thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is on the web.xml and spring-mvc-dispatcher.xml, I have `<component-scan ...>`, those create the config two times (I don't know why). Removing the label `<component-scan ...>` I solve all.